# a summary of frequentist view in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian

I have read ESL and PRML,the PRML is easy for me to understand, as well with the Bayesian view.But the PRML is too difficult for people without statistic background like me .Is there anybody able to give a summary  of frequentist view or explain it briefly?

Comment: I dare to say that ESL is even harder without a little background knowledge in statistics.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit hard, in my opinion, to make it brief. It's like banalizing two different *visions of a world*.

Nevertheless, a very short reduction to a single argument can be this:

- frequentists do not treat hidden parameters as random variables and do not seek to describe them by subjective priors.

[Here](http://jsteinhardt.wordpress.com/2012/10/31/beyond-bayesians-and-frequentists/) is a good discussion that goes in depth touching arguments as parameter estimation algorithmic complexty in the two approaches.

[This](http://hunch.net/?p=8) is an old discussion, arisen in the famous Langford's blog.

And, to confirm my point about the requirment of a bit of statistics at least to understand the different perspectives, here is a [video](http://videolectures.net/mlss09uk_jordan_bfway/).